# Using md-stretch-tabs with Tab Nav Bar

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I need to stretch the tabs to fill up the width of the page.
How should I use md-stretch-tabs in the bottom mention code? Please advice.
Thank you

```
  <nav md-tab-nav-bar aria-label="weather navigation links">
    <a md-tab-link
       *ngFor="let tabLink of tabLinks; let i = index"
       [routerLink]="tabLink.link"
       [active]="activeLinkIndex === i"
       (click)="activeLinkIndex = i">
      {{tabLink.label}}
    </a>
  </nav>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using SCSS or SASS you can use the following:

```
.mat-tab-links {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;

    .mat-tab-link {
        display: table-cell;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it is working, however the braces are position wrongly.

.mat-tab-links {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}

.mat-tab-link {
    display: table-cell;
}

Comment: for css - yea, but I'm using saas, forgot to mention that

Answer (score 0):

Set min-width style in percentage as below,

```
this.minWidth=100/this.routeLinks.length;

<a md-tab-link [style.min-width]="minWidth + '%'" >...
```

**[LIVE DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/c7XCRwngWNsXmTEUriW6?p=preview)**

Answer (score 0):

I'm using flex box and the accepted answer wasn't working for me.

here is my solution..

```
.mat-tab-link {
    display: flex;
    flex-grow: 1;
}
```

enjoy..